# Application_Start event not firing when there is app_offline.htm file is present

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

I want to enable/disable the website by introducing app_offline.htm file in the application root directory. This, I want it dynamically from a setting in database. When true, I am moving the app_offline.htm file to root, and when set to false, I am moving the file from root to another directory.

I have written the logic in global.asax file **Application_Start** event.
But this event is not firing when the app_offline.htm file is present in the root directory.

Below is my code snippet I tried:

```
{
    if (offlineMode == "1")
    {
        destination = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
        source = Path.Combine(destination, "Offline");
        MakeApplicationOffline(destination, source);
    }
    else
    {
        source = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
        destination = Path.Combine(source, "Offline");
        MakeApplicationOffline(destination, source);
    }
}

private static void MakeApplicationOffline(string destinationPath, string sourcePath)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
    {
        foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath).GetFiles("*.htm"))
        {
            file.MoveTo($@"{destinationPath}\{file.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your application is offline, why would it fire an Application_Start event?

Comment: I wanted to make online by database settings. I wanted to check If i can do it through app_start event

Comment: No, you can't. Because the app doesn't start when it's offline. An app that is offline cannot start itself because it is offline and isn't running.

Comment: Oh Ok. Any suggestion how this can be done ?

Comment: If you like the database flag, you could keep the overall design but deploy another application, either as a Windows Service or even a simple console program that you schedule with Task Scheduler. The program would check the database flag and deploy the file as needed. A more modern approach would skip the database altogether and deploy or remove the file using a simple Azure pipeline.